# .htaccess rewrite rule does not work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having some trouble with the Rewrite rule in .htaccess and none of the other answers on here seem to do the trick!

Basically the code below works

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ test.php
```

However as soon as I add anything else it does not!  The two lines of code below do not work at all

```
RewriteRule ^project-([0-9]+)\.html$ project.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^project.php?id=82$ test.php
```

When I get this working I eventually want to take the project title from the page and insert it in the url (just like this site if you take a look in the URL) AND turn all .php to .html but I have seem to have fallen at the first hurdle!

Any ideas anyone?  Any help will be gratefully received!

Comment: With non-obvious problems it's sometimes necessary to set up the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following edits to your code below

```
#escape the . so it does not match indexsphp etc
#added [NC,L] so it is not case sensitive and last rule processed
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ test.php [NC,L]

#added [NC,L] so it is not case sensitive and last rule processed 
# and QSA to pass through any existing query string  values
RewriteRule ^project-([0-9]+)\.html$ project.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

If this rule

> RewriteRule ^project.php?id=82$ test.php

is intended to match only when the id=82, then it will not work and needs to be re-written as follows

```
#if the query string has an id=82
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=82 [NC]
#and resource is project.php, send it to test.php
RewriteRule ^project\.php$ test.php [NC,L]
```

**EDIT**

> I would like to take project.php?id=82 and change to project-82.html

See rules below

```
#if the original request has project.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /project\.php [NC]
#capture the id param
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
#and 301 redirect to project-id.html
RewriteRule . project-%1.html? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That second part worked a treat to get it to redirect to test.php!

Comment: I added ([0-9]+) in place of the 82 and that worked great too.  Do you know how I would get it to redirect to project-82.html or whatever the ID is?  Thanks!!

Comment: @user1134974 I don't understand the question: can you give me an example

Comment: sorry, say the ID=82.  I would like to take project.php?id=82 and change to project-82.html

Comment: Thanks for your edit.  I get an error now saying that The requested URL /home/sites/siteurl.co.uk/public_html/project-90.html was not found on this server.  Also in the address bar is says http://www.siteurl.co.uk/home/sites/siteurl.co.uk/public_html/project-90.html?id=90

Comment: @5ummer5 Make sure you have a `RewriteBase /` before all your rules, just after the `RewriteEngine on` directive

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the issue with the extra /home/sites but it adds ?id=82 to the end.  Like this http://www.siteurl.co.uk/project-82.html?id=82

Comment: @5ummer5 add a `?` to the rule i.e. `RewriteRule . project-%1.html? [L,R=301]`.  If this is the correct answer, then also accept this answer :-)

Comment: that solved the extra ?id=82 but it does not render the page for some reason.  I get - Not Found - The requested URL /project-84.html was not found on this server.  It's so close now!  Thank you for all your help so far!!

Comment: Yeah, only only started using this today so not ranked at all!  I will start a new question now and post the URL in a second.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766231/htaccess-url-rewrite-requested-url-not-found-on-server

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the `index.html` rewrite works fine I guess you already have this, but instead of assuming I suggest still that you make sure that rewrites are actually enabled. I always put this first in my .htaccess files:

```
RewriteEngine On
```