# htaccess URL rewrite - requested URL not found on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Having an issue where the URL rewrite is running but the server will not display the contents.  My .htaccess file is

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /project\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule . project-%1.html? [R=301]
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Sorry, here is some more info!

I want to rewrite

```
    www.siteurl.co.uk/project.php?id=82
```

to

```
    www.siteurl.co.uk/project-82.html
```

The code in the .htaccess rewrites the URL perfectly but the page does not display.  I get a

```
    404 The requested URL /project-82.html was not found on this server.
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: You forgot to describe your issue and ask a question

Comment: Without knowing what you want to match? Its pretty much impossible to know where to start

Comment: Sorry guys this was following on from another question and I forgot to add all the info!  I have edited it now!

Comment: Can you confirm that the rules above are your entire .htaccess file?

Comment: Yep, that is all that is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one half of the solution, creating the pretty urls.  What is missing is the other half, sending the pretty urls to an application for processing as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /project\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . project-%1.html? [R=301]

#you need this rule to process your www.siteurl.co.uk/project-82.html request
RewriteRule ^project-([0-9]+)\.html$ project.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting     `RewriteRule ^project-%1.html? [R=301]` instead of the `.`

Comment: Thats for the reply.  I just tried that and it didnt rewrite the URL at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the "[A-Z]{3-9}\ " is for? maybe I'm missing something?

But maybe something like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^project\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . project-%1.html? [R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/project\.php project-%1.html? [R=301]
```

Note that this is just off the top of my head, and I didn't test it.

EDIT: Just adjusted the second example which had an extra slash in it, and tested it out on my webserver (note that I'm using IIS/URLRewrite, but should be same):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^project\.php project-%1.html? [R=301]
```

I entered **http://localhost/project.php?id=123** and it went to **http://localhost/project-123.html**

**But I think I missed something...** you say the url rewrite is working, and the url is changing but you're getting a 404? In that case then your rewrite sounds fine - and something else is not permitting your html files to be accessed (or they don't exist)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I am afraid neither of those worked and the URL stayed the same.  Im not sure what the "[A-Z]{3-9}\ " is for but it works with it.  Apart from loading the page though!

Comment: That edit did the trick and the URL rewrite works.  You are correct in saying that the project-82.html file does not exist.  I just want the URL to read www.siteurl.co.uk/project-82.html rather than www.siteurl.co.uk/project.php?id=82.